# Strange symbols while executing win command file

Tags: windows-xp, command-line

Every time I create .cmd file and execute it windows finds strange symbols at start of file: ie:

```
REM ping
ping localhost
```

leads to

```
C:\>я╗┐REM ping
'я╗┐' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
...
```

I've checked encoding of .cmd file and it seems to be fine. Even HEX editor didn't show any strange in file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a BOM, a [**Byte Order Mark**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte-order_mark), although I do not recognize for which encoding. Make sure you save the file with ASCII or ANSI encoding.

If it's not a BOM (because it should normally show up in a hex editor), maybe it's a problem with the Command Prompt. Have you tried using .bat instead of .cmd ?

Comment: Great! Changing text encoging from UTF-8 to windows-1250 solves the issue! Thank you Snark!